# Control the height of a stacked column chart - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to use this chart here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/) but I want to control the height of the bars with a different number and use the values within the bar to show their percentages

This is chart in case my link doesn't work

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

Comment: So something [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/uhcrgfmq/)

Comment: @HalvorStrand Thanks for the reply. I thought that people would get confused. You are still working with the numbers you have within the bar to produce the height. I want the height to be for example 76 regardless if I had 5,3,2 in my dataset. I want to the height to be an independent number

Comment: Hm. Could you give a complete example (or image) of how you expect it to look, compared with what you expect to put in your data?

Comment: @HalvorStrand Basically I have an algorithm that calculates a score based on answers. The score ranges from 0 to 100. So you may have 6 'responses' with 3 of them scoring 100 and 3 of them scoring 50 so the overall score would be 75(height) and the bar would be separated in two colors showing the 6 responses. As it is now the bar height would be 6 instead of 75. Hope that would make things more clear.

Comment: You need to process data on your own. I do not understand what should be the final effect,  but if you want a stack to have a fixed value, you need to add missing part as the last series. http://jsfiddle.net/3oc449pd/